# Second Algebraic Dual Space

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

I still didn't understand what is Second Dual Space. From class, I was told that:
$X^{**}=\{g_{x}:x \in X\}$ which $g_{x}$ is a map from algebraic dual space $X^{*}$ to scalar field $K$ of vector space $X$. $g_x$ is defined by $g_x(f)=f(x)$.
Then, I met $C$ which is called **canonical mapping** and map from vector space $X$ to second algebraic dual space $X^{**}$ defined by $Cx=g_x$. The book state that $C$ is injective but not always surjective.
What I didn't understand is why $C$ isn't always surjective? From the definition of element in $X^{**}$ and from the statement that $C$ is injective, then $C$ must be surjective. Or I might be wrong define elements in $X^{**}$?
And I'm using the book from Erwin Kreyszig - Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications

Comment: $X^{**}=\{g_{x}:x \in X\}$ is not the definition of the second dual space.  The second dual space is the dual of the dual space.

Comment: @Aweygan right, I'm sorry. This book said it's Second Algebraic Dual Space. Is it same with Second Dual Space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're wrong about the definition of $X^{**}$.  From Kreyszig, page 107:

> We may go one step further and consider the algebraic dual $(X^*)^*$ of $X^*$, *whose elements are the linear functionals defined on $X^*$*... and call it the **second algebraic dual space of $X$**.

He then goes on to explain that for any $x$, $g_x$ is an element of $X^{**}$.

Notably, however, there is nothing about the definition of $X^{**}$ which guarantees that *every* element $g \in X^{**}$, that is every $g:X^* \to \Bbb C$, has the form $g_x$ for some $x \in X$.  In fact, if $X$ is an infinite dimensional normed space (and if we take the axiom of choice), then this is necessarily **not** the case.

---

For example: take $X\subset \ell^1$ to be the set of sequences for which all but finitely many elements are $0$.

Let $\{e_i\}_{i \in \Bbb N}$ be the canonical basis of $X$ (so for example, $e_1 = (1,0,0\dots)$); note that this is a Hamel basis for our space.  Every functional $f$ is determined by its values over these elements, since
$$
f(\sum_{i} \alpha_i e_i) = \sum_i \alpha_i f(e_i)
$$
Thus, for every sequence $(\beta_i)_{i \in \Bbb N}$, there is an associated $f$ with $f(e_i) = \beta_i$.

Now, consider the subspace of $U \subset X^*$ consiting of $f \in X^*$ such that
$$
\sup_{i \in \Bbb N}|f(e_i)| < \infty
$$
We may define the linear map $g:U \to \Bbb C$ by
$$
g(f) = \sup_{i \in \Bbb N} f(e_i)
$$
and by the axiom of choice, we may write $X^* = U \oplus V$ for some subspace $V$, and we may extend $g$ to all of $X^*$ by defining $g|_V = 0$.

Note that $g \in X^{**}$, but there is no $x \in X$ such that for *every* $f\in X$, $g(f) = f(x)$.

Comment: Do you happen to know whether the last assertion requires (part of) the axiom of choice?

Comment: @DanielFischer It almost certainly does; I'll say so.

Comment: So, It's not necessary that every $g \in X^{**}$ has the form $g_x$? If it's so, then how we define $g(f)$ if it has no form $g_x$? I'm really confused.

Comment: It's hard to come up with an explicit example, but I added one in my latest edit.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. So, element in $X^{**}$ is a function that maps from $X^*$ to $K$ and the definition is not always $g(f)=f(x)$. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah one more question, Is there any necessary condition that $g \in X^{**}$ must hold or $g$ is just a function?

Comment: $g$ is just a function; that's what makes $X^{**}$ the *algebraic* double dual (as opposed to the *topological* or *continuous* dual).

Answer (score 0):

If we take $c_0 , \ell_1 , \ell_{\infty}. $ Then $c_0^{\ast} =\ell_1 , c_0^{\ast\ast}=\ell_1^{\ast}=\ell_{\infty}. $ Then the functional $\xi (x) =\sum_j x_j $ is not in the image $\kappa (c_0 )$ where $\kappa $ is the canonical mapping but $\xi \in c_0^{\ast\ast}=\ell_1^{\ast}=\ell_{\infty}.$

Comment: One question, what's the dimention of $c_0, l_1, l_{\infty}$? Are they infinite dimentional vector spaces?

Comment: $\mbox{dim} (c_0 ) =\mathfrak{c}$

Comment: In this answer, you're using *continuous* dual as opposed to the *algebraic* dual.