# Give an example of canonical mapping which is one one but not onto?

Tags: functional-analysis

Give an example    of canonical mapping which is one one but not onto

Here  Canonical mapping   mean    $C:X \to X^{**}   $ where X is vectors space and $X^{**}$ is second algebraic dual space

**My attempt**  :     Let $x \in X$ be fixed, and let $g_x \colon X^* \to X^{**}$ be defined as
$$g_x(f) \colon= f(x) \; \; \; \forall f \in X^*.$$
Then $g_x$ is a linear functional on $X^*$ so that $g_x \in X^{**}$.

Then the mapping $C \colon X \to X^{**}$ defined by
$$Cx \colon= g_x \; \; \; \forall x \in X$$
is one one and onto

Suppose that, for some $x$, $y \in X$,then we have
$$Cx = Cy.$$
Then
$$g_x = g_y.$$
So, for all $f \in X^*$, we have
$$g_x(f) =g(f(x))= g_y(f)=g(f(y)).$$
This implies that $f(x) = f(y)$ and so $x-y \in ker(f)$ for all linear functionals $f$ defined on $X$,

From given above proof $C$ is both one-one and onto

My confusion : I need  a $C$ which is one one but not onto. Im not able to find out

Comment: Why do you think $C$ is surjective?

Comment: @MaoWao here $f$ is one one  for simple example  take $f : R \to R$ define by $f(x)=x$ is both one one and onto

Comment: Sure, the identity is a bijection. But what does this have to do with my question why the map $C$ from the OP should be surjective?

Comment: im sorry  @MaoWao im also confusing

Comment: Anyway, an answer to your question is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984572/second-algebraic-dual-space?rq=1